# Nginx not routing two containers on different ports

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, flask, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have two container 1.Flask backend app 2. Angular frontend app. Flask app is forwarding port 8001 whereas angular app on port 80. Both work fine when accessing directly. I am now trying to use a NGINX container as reverse proxy to redirect the urls localhost:5001 for Flask app, and localhost:80 for Angular app. I am following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/workflow-multiple-containers-docker-compose) guide. here is my docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'my_db'
      MYSQL_USER: 'root'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: '****'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '****'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql

  nginx:
      restart: always
      build: ../nginx/.
      depends_on:
        - api_server
        - web_ui
      ports:
        - '80:80'

  api_server:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      SECRET_KEY: ****
      FLASK_ENV: local
      SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI_DEV: mysql+mysqldb://root:****@db:3306/my_db
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"

  web_ui:
    depends_on:
      - api_server
    image: web_ui_local
    environment:
      API_URL: api_server:8001
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
      - '/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - '8002:80'
```

nginx Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:latest
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

and default.conf

```
upstream web_ui {
  server web_ui:5001;
}

upstream api_server {
  server api_server:5002;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;

  location /api_server {
    proxy_pass http://api_server;
  }

  location /web_ui {
    proxy_pass http://web_ui;
  }
}
```

Cannot access localhost:5001 neither localhost:5002. nginx logs says this when accessing localhost

```
2020/05/08 16:39:57 [error] 6#6: *1 "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.21.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
172.21.0.1 - - [08/May/2020:16:39:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/xx.xx.xx.xx Safari/537.36" "-"
```

**UPDATE:**

accessing `localhost/api_server` gives me following error;

```
2020/05/08 19:03:01 [error] 6#6: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.21.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /api_server HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.21.0.3:5002/api_server", host: "localhost"
```

Where `172.21.0.3` is api_server container ip. so this response is expected bcuz its not listening on port 5002. Changing this to port 8001 redirects to api_server with 404 response bcuz there is no such route `GET /api_server` in flask app.

**UPDATE 2:**
I made default.conf much simple based on my requirements;

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name 127.0.0.1;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://web_ui;
  }
}

server {
  listen 5001;
  server_name 127.0.0.1;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://api_server:8001;
  }
}
```

I removed the `ports:'8002:80'` from web_ui, and the above get successful redirect to Angular app on `localhost`. But `localhost:5001` is still not working (no response) :(

**Update 3:**
port forwarding `5001` from nginx port was missing. Can now access OpenApi Docs on localhost:5001 too.

Comment: You're proxying only /api_server location to api and only /web_ui location to web ui but your error log is for / location which is not proxied. Does it make sense to you or do you have another error log showing proxied location? If it's the former but not clear enough, I can give you more detailed answer, lmk.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, I expect it to show these logs on / location bcuz it's not proxied. But I see no logs on nginx container when accessing localhost:5001, & 5002.

Comment: Ok, I see - so make a call to say /api_server - and see what happens.

Comment: localhost/api_server gives this error 
`2020/05/08 18:52:08 [error] 6#6: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.21.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /api_server HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.21.0.3:5002/api_server", host: "localhost"`
Where 172.21.0.3 is the ip address of api_server container

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem, actually my usecase was much simpler then what I was implementing. I am using `default.conf` file as mentioned in question's **Update 2** and exposing ports `5001` and `80` from nginx container and removing from api_server and web_ui.

services `nginx` of docker-compose.yaml

```
  nginx:
      restart: always
      build: ../nginx/.
      depends_on:
        - api_server
        - web_ui
      ports:
        - '80:80'         # for Angular app
        - '5001:5001'     # for backend flask app
```